# Codeigniter automatic redirect to a friendly url not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, dynamic, routes

I need to redirect the url http://domainname/foldername/functionname/dynamicstring to http://domainname/foldername/dynamicstring .

I have added this in my route

```html
$route['([a-zA-z_]+)'] = 'controllername/functionname/$1';
```

and i am able to access this url http://domainname/foldername/dynamicstring only when i type it in url. 
Otherwise on clicking buttons, the site is redirecting to http://domainname/foldername/functionname/dynamicstring which now shows 404 not found.

**View page code**

```html
<a href="<?php echo base_url('functionname');?>/<?php echo $dynamicstring ;?>"></a>
```

**Controller**

```html
public function functionname($dynamicstring)
  {
    $data['fun1'] = $this->Modelname->fun1($dynamicstring);
    $data['fun2'] = $this->Modelname->fun2($dynamicstring);
    $this->load->view('folder/viewpage',$data);
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried `$route['functionname/(:any)'] = 'foldername/controllername/functionname/$1';`

Comment: yes its not working

Comment: `$route['foldername/(:any)'] = 'foldername/controllername/functionname/$1';` then you need to call it as `base_url('foldername/your-dynamic-string')` in your view.

Comment: its not working.. functionname is needed actually in view page. need to fetch dynamic-string from function name

Comment: Then, please share your related `route code`,  `view code` and the `controller code`

Comment: qustion is updated with the codes

Answer (score 0):

So, I created a demo and it works for me. I've explained in the code itself.
**routes.php**

```
// As the name suggests here {functionname} is any function inside the controller, controller name is {controller} which is inside folder named {folder}.
$route['functionname/(:any)'] = 'folder/controller/functionname/$1'; // if you want {foldername} here then replace {functionname} with {foldername}
```

**Controller.php**

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function functionname($dynamicstring){
        echo $dynamicstring;
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<?php 
    //get the value in $dynamicstring(your condition)
    $dynamicstring = 'harry-potter'; //say harry-potter
?>

<a href="<?php echo base_url("functionname/$dynamicstring"); ?>">My name</a>
<!--<a href="<?php echo base_url("foldername/$dynamicstring"); ?>">My name</a>-->
```

> **OUTPUT:**
>   [image: output image]

As you can see, it works fine for me. See if it helps you.